Flutter FirebaseSDK CocoaPods issue could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/RemoteConfig"
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
firebase_analytics: Using Firebase SDK version '10.22.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '10.22.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
Run script to upload symbols already exists.
firebase_crashlytics: Using Firebase SDK version '10.22.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_remote_config: Using Firebase SDK version '10.22.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/RemoteConfig":
  In Podfile:
    ar_flutter_plugin (from `.symlinks/plugins/ar_flutter_plugin/ios`) was resolved to 0.6.2, which depends on
      ARCore/CloudAnchors (~> 1.32.0) was resolved to 1.32.0, which depends on
        ARCore/GARSession (= 1.32.0) was resolved to 1.32.0, which depends on
          Firebase/RemoteConfig (< 10.0, >= 8.0)

    firebase_remote_config (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_remote_config/ios`) was resolved to 4.3.17, which depends on
      Firebase/RemoteConfig (= 10.22.0)

We are using version platform :ios, '14.0' and also using ar_flutter_plugin. so that facing that issue in pod file

You need to update the package from your pubspec.yaml

May I know which version is compatible? FirebaseSDK  package version please

To find out which package needs updating and the different versions! he commands it “flutter pub outdated”,
